# Excel 2010 Sum Column by Date

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this macro that I use to sum total entries by date. The macro can be run two or three times per day which causes a problem as it wants to sum by date. When I run it and it places the total in the last cell in column E, I want that total number to remain the next time I run the macro, but right now it erases the last entry and sums the new total plus the previous total. How can this be changed?  I hope this makes sense the way I am explaining it.

```
Sub Sum_TodaysDate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Dim LastRow As Long, iCount As Long
Dim icell As Range
Dim dSplit As Variant
Dim dIndex As Date


LastRow = sh.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
iCount = 0

For Each icell In sh.Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    dSplit = Split(icell.Value, " ")
    dIndex = Format(dSplit(0), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    If dIndex = Date Then
        iCount = iCount + 1
        icell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "|"
    End If
Next icell


sh.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = iCount
sh.Range("E" & LastRow).Font.Color = vbRed


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: "I want that total number to remain the next time I run the macro, but right now it erases the last entry and sums the new total plus the previous total. " What do you mean?

Comment: Some sample of what your data looks like and your expected output would make this much more answerable.

Comment: Before I run the macro I am automatically adding rows before running it which are just job rows. I am using this macro to simply sum the job rows and enter a number. So the user creates 7 job rows and this macro enters a "|" in each cell with the same date and then number 7 at the last cell in that column.  When this gets filled out again later the same day I don't want the number 7 to go away as it does now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to leave anything that is currently in column E untouched by the macro, so that previous counts remain in place, change the line that says:

```
icell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "|"
```

to

```
If IsEmpty(icell.Offset(0, 1)) Then
    icell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "|"
Endif
```

---

If you want the new count to only be the count of records added since the previous time the macro was run (and the data is in date order), this could be modified to be:

```
If IsEmpty(icell.Offset(0, 1)) Then
    icell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "|"
Else
    iCount = 0
Endif
```

Comment: Your second one is just what I needed.... EXCELLENT!  Thank you very much.